# ExoPlayer sometimes returns negative duration for an mp3 file from url

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm making an app where I play .mp3 files from the URL. I'm using the latest version of ExoPlayer 2.11.4.

What I need to do is get the total duration of the audio from the url so I can use it in my custom audio player.

The urls I'm using are of this type: https://myserver.net/.../audio/439688e0c3626d39d3ef3.mp3?token=6oz-22-2sa-9yh-7e-2iak

The problem is that sometimes my code works correctly most of the time and returns the correct duration. But sometimes what I get is a negative number: -9223372036854775807

And that doesn't allow my code to work properly. My code where I get the duration is this:

```
fun getDuration(url: String, context: Context) {
        exoPlayer?.release()

        exoPlayer = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build()
        val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "ExoPlayer"))
        val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url))

        exoPlayer?.prepare(mediaSource)

        exoPlayer?.addListener(object : Player.EventListener {
            override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
                if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY) {
                    val realDurationMillis: Long? = exoPlayer?.getDuration()
                    currentDuration = realDurationMillis
                    if (currentDuration != null) {
                        if (currentDuration!! > 0) {
                            exoPlayer?.release()
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @iamkdblue unfortunately not, and I am no longer working on that project

Answer (score 5):

[`C.TIME_UNSET`](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/common/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/C.java#L51) is defined as `Long.MIN_VALUE + 1` which is where your -9223372036854775807 comes from.

```
  /**
   * Special constant representing an unset or unknown time or duration. Suitable for use in any
   * time base.
   */
  public static final long TIME_UNSET = Long.MIN_VALUE + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I spent hours looking for a solution for this problem. I took help from the automatic notification feature of media3. Once you set up the controller, from controller.get(). You can use that to get the total duration.

```
val sessionToken =
        SessionToken(context, ComponentName(context, ExoplayerService::class.java))
    controller = MediaController.Builder(context, sessionToken).buildAsync()
    controller.addListener({
        val mediaController = controller.get()
        mediaController.addListener(object : Player.Listener {
            //to sync with inside app player media play/pause button
            override fun onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying: Boolean) {
                super.onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying)
                val duration = mediaController.duration
                Log.d(LOG, "Duration Controller: $duration")
            }
        })
    }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor())
```

This seems to be working in my case. If I am doing something wrong, let me know.